# mongoimport without installing the database

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

Is there an easy solution to install the mongoimport tool but not install all the mongo packages?

The mongoimport tool would be used on machine A but the data would be saved to machine B.

Currently, I have two machines. They both have mongo installed. However, machine A uses mongoimport and the connection points to machine B. I'd like to be able to use machine A without needing to install all other packages that comes along with the mongo installation.

Comment: Which OSes run on machine A and B, respectively?

Comment: Can vary. Could be Ubuntu. Could be macOS. @MarkusWMahlberg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Ubuntu

On Ubuntu, follow the [documentation for installing MongoDB CE on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

1. Add the package signing key

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
   ```
2. Add a source file to the apt configuration

   - Ubuntu 12.04

     ```
     echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu precise/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
     ```
   - Ubuntu 14.04

     ```
     echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
     ```
   - Ubuntu 16.04

     ```
     echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
     ```
3. Reload local package database

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install the `mongoldb-org-tools` package, which contains `mongoimport`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org-tools
   ```

## MacOS

Install [macports](https://www.macports.org), if you have not yet. Then, do

```
sudo port selfupdate && sudo port install mongo-tools
```

## Notes

Personally, I think it is a Very Bad Idea™ to remotely import data. Your connection may easily become the bottleneck and depending on the number of documents you are going to import this may be severely limiting the performance. Furthermore, a remote connection is more likely to break by orders of magnitude, which would leave you with a partially imported file.

I'd rather use [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) on the remote machine, start the import, suspend the terminal and wait for the import to complete:

```
$ screen
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

Copyright (c) 1993-2002 Juergen Weigert, Michael Schroeder
Copyright (c) 1987 Oliver Laumann

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software
Foundation; either version 2, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with
this program (see the file COPYING); if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.

Send bugreports, fixes, enhancements, t-shirts, money, beer & pizza to
screen@uni-erlangen.de


                    [Press Space or Return to end.]
$ mongoimport <your opts here>
<ctrl+a,ctrl+d>
$ screen -r # to reattach the detached terminal session
```

This way, you can safely terminate your terminal session when the import is detached.

Comment: This is awesome. I will try it out tomorrow and then accept this answer. Thanks!